# Continuous function on Stone space

Tags: general-topology

A Stone space is one in which distinct points can be separated by clopen sets. How can I show that there exists, for any $x$ and $y$ such that $x \neq y$, a continuous function $f: X \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ such that $f(x) \neq f(y)$?

Not sure what to try that would be helpful. I've tried explicitly constructing such a map but to no avail. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ be a clopen set containing $x$ but not $y$, and define

$$f:X\to\{0,1\}:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }x\in U\\
1,&\text{if }x\in X\setminus U\;.
\end{cases}$$

You need only verify that $f$ is continuous.